# WPF Issues Creating Window on Secondary Screen Only On Certain Hardware Configurations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I'm using the standard recommendation for creating a Window and having it display on a secondary monitor:

I use the following to get the screens available:

```
Screen[] availableScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
```

Extract the working area of the target screen (second screen in my case, not the primary screen):

```
secondaryScreenWorkingArea = availableScreens[1].WorkingArea;
```

When creating the window, set the location properties based on the working area (before calling Show()):

```
Left = secondaryScreenWorkingArea.Left;
Top = secondaryScreenWorkingArea.Top;
Width = secondaryScreenWorkingArea.Width;
Height = secondaryScreenWorkingArea.Height;
```

Some other things to note about the window:

- It is a fullscreen window that is intended to span the entire second
  display
- It is not the main application window
- It is hidden from the taskbar, it is intended to be supplemental to
  the main application window
- WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
- ShowInTaskbar="False"
- WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
- Running on Windows 10 Enterprise V 1809

Below is a rundown is different configurations that I've tested, and only one of them is not behaving correctly:

- When I run this on a workstation setup with two 1920x1080 displays, 100% display scaling, it works as expected.
- When I run this on a workstation setup with two 1920x1080 displays, 150% display scaling, it works as expected.
- When I run this on a workstation setup with a 1920x1080 display and a secondary USB display (800x480) connected, 100% display scaling, it works
- When I run this on a workstation setup with a 1920x1080 display and a secondary USB display (800x480) connected, 150% display scaling, it works
- When I run this on a Microsoft Surface Go with the main surface display (1800x1200) and a secondary USB display (800x480) connected to the surface dock, 100% display scaling, it works
- When I run this on a Microsoft Surface Go with the main surface display (1800x1200) and a secondary USB display (800x480) connected to the surface dock, 150% display scaling, it DOES NOT work. Instead, once Window.Show() is called, this is triggering the window to relocate to the primary display (The surface go screen). I noticed this because I am receiving a LocationChanged event for the window during my call to Window.Show() and see the Width and Height properties have updated to the sizing of the Surface Go display (1800x1200). But, curiously, the Top and Left properties are NOT updated even though the window has moved.

As you can see from the cases above, it seems to be an issue with Display scaling + the Surface Go. On my workstation, I forced the same resolution as the Surface go (1800x1200) and set display scaling to 150%, but could not replicate the issue from the Surface Go

Furthermore, I performed some testing with another USB display with a slightly higher resolution (1024x600) and have noticed that the same issue occurs, only on the Surface Go, but this time it required me pushing the display scaling to 200% before the issue began to occur in that configuration.

Several things I've tried, but none produced any solutions to this issue:

- Tried various configurations of dpiAware and dpiAwareness. These changed the scaling of the coordinates I received when grabbing the AvailableScreens, but using scaled/unscaled coordinates had not affect on this issue
- Restarting the Surface Go after changing the display scaling option (per the "Some apps won't respond to scaling changes until you sign of" message displayed in the Display Settings
- Tried setting WindowState = WindowState.Maximized both before and after the Loaded event and both yielded the same result.

Any help or other ideas for things to try would be appreciated, not sure if this is a WPF, Windows 10 or a Microsoft Surface Go issue.